# Cast on LineageOS 20

Tags: lineageos, chromecast, miracast

LineageOS 20, which is based on Android 13, has settings for some screen cast technology, even without having GApps installed. They settings can be found at **Settings > Connected devices > Connection preferences > Cast**. The UI simply refers to it as Cast, without giving any details on the technology involved or how to set it up.

As per my research, there are two technologies that Android has supported over the years:

- Miracast, an open standard, introduced with Android 4.2–4.4 and gradually phased out starting with Android 6, ending with Android 9,
- Google Cast, a proprietary protocol, which requires GApps on the device.

The UI simply tells me no nearby devices were found. I don’t see any controls to search for supported devices (in fact I don’t have any, because I don’t even know which technology they would need to support).

Does LineageOS 20 without GApps come with a complete stack for any screen cast technology? If so, which? If not, can this functionality be added? What would I need to install? If so, is there a way to achieve this without installing any proprietary add-ons?

Comment: Thanks for the link. The comment actually states that Miracast was supported up to LOS 16.0; LOS 17.1 only supports Chromecast on older devices (no idea what that means for new ones).

Comment: according to https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/qkys0j/comment/hj30lro/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button, Miracast was re-added in LOS 18.1. The poster is a LOS dev, who presumably knows what he’s talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my hands on a device with Miracast support today, and here is my experience. Setup is not 100% self-explanatory.

AOSP had Miracast support up to Android 9, though some vendors started phasing it out earlier. LineageOS benefited from this until LOS 16.1. LOS 17.1 has no Miracast support, but it was backported starting with LOS 18.1 for select devices. As of LOS 20, it is still available. The following was tested on a Fairphone 4:

- Prepare your display so it announces itself over the air.
- On your device, go to **Settings > Connected devices > Connection preferences > Cast**.
- Tap the three-button menu and enable wireless display.
- You will see a bunch of options appearing; make sure **Enable listen mode** and **Enable autonomous GO** are on. (They reset themselves if you leave the screen.)
- Available devices should now appear at the bottom of the list. Tap your device to connect to it.

Cast is not perfectly stable. The first time I connected to the external display, it would just give me garbage. After I disconnected, I was unable to reconnect; disabling and then re-enabling wireless display fixed this for me. The second connection attempt finally worked.

Be aware that wireless display is just as prone to radio reception/interference issues as WiFi itself. Especially videos may appear jerky, freeze briefly or show compression artifacts if bandwidth is impeded.

All in all, it works if there is no other option and/or you are mostly displaying still images. I wouldn’t recommend it for watching movies, though.